# Let X have a uniform distribution $U (a,b)$ for $a<b$. Compute the moment generating function $M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X have a uniform distribution $U (a,b)$ for $a<b$. Compute the moment generating function $M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$.

I get $\frac {e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)}$

I have to deal two different cases $t=0$ and  $t \neq 0$

For $t=0$, is it undefined?
For $t \neq 0$, can I leave like $\frac {e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t = 0$, then $e^{tX} = e^0 = 1$ for all values of $X$, so the expectation is just $M_X(0) = E[1] = 1$.

Also, the expression you have written for $M_X(t)$ for $t \neq 0$ is correct, and cannot be simplified further.